# What is the english meaning of taqwa?

Tags: quran-translation

Selamun Aleykum,
I heard there is no single word or even single phrase to adequately translate **taqwa** into English.  This is the reason for inaccuracies in this meaning for Quranic translations.

I heard it takes 3 sentences minimum to describe taqwa.  Please indicate if the following is correct.  My son asked so it is important that it is.

1. To worship Allah only and obey all of Allah's requirements for Islam as shown by our prophet (pbuh).
2. To abstain from anything that is Haram.
3. To abstain from anything that is makru (questionable )

Comment: [Piety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piety)?

Comment: See: [Taqwa](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taqwa)